# Do different mobs give different amounts of EXP

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Do all enemies on average give the same amount of EXP when killed? Or is there a tier of highest to lowest EXP from a kill.

Answer (score 1):

Each monster gives a different amount of experience. You can see that [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience#Leveling_up). Screenshot of that page to avoid linkrot:

[image]